# checking several Lists List<int> for a certain number doesn't work

Tags: c#, wpf

I am trying to know if a number I pass to the function is contained in any of the lists I have. Here is an extract of the code. I have initialized the list grid as it is said in many similar posts here, but that doesn't work.

The error says

> "System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'"

referring to grid. I know it seems duplicated, but I have checked the others posts similar to this and I can not find a specific answer to my problem.

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    //This list is much bigger
    public List<int> grid1 = new List<int>();
    public List<int> grid2 = new List<int>();
    public List<int> grid3 = new List<int>();
    public List<int> grid4 = new List<int>();
    public List<int> grid5 = new List<int>();

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private bool numberValide(int number, int Grid)  // Grid {1..5}
    {
        List<int>   = new List<int>();
        grid = (List<int>)this.FindName("grid" + Grid);
        if (grid != null)
        {
            if (!grid.Contains(number))
            {
                grid.Add(number);     //the error is here
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            grid.Add(number);   //error also here
            return true;
        }           
    }
}
```

Comment: The code you have posted wont even compile.  You are expected to include a [MCVE] with your question

Comment: I am trying to edit it, but it says I can not because it was edited by you. It also an extract showing the part that gives error

Comment: The second one in the `else` clause is obvious. You have `if (grid != null)`, so in the `else` clause `grid == null` and obviously you can't add anything to it.

Comment: Also, I dont think `grid` will resolve to a `List<int>`, `FindName()` is likely trying to find a control in the window.  You cannot programaticaly access class variables like this without reflection

Comment: But all the list aren't null at the beginning?

Comment: Matt's point is correct. What's the error you're getting at the first grid.Add()??

Comment: The lists being null dont matter, the result of `FindName()` will be null because you dont have a _control_ by that name.  Then when you cast it to `List<int>` that instance will be null

Comment: Ah, then, the FindName() method works only for controls, not for a list for example

Comment: I suspect the problem here is that you think `FindName` will let you find a field in a class. That is not what it does. It finds a *control* in a *window*. `grid1`, `grid2`, etc are **not** controls. They are fields

Comment: @AbdelHidalgo yes, you understand.  I think you have a problematic design though, why so many Lists in your class?  Why not use a `Dictionary<int, List<int>`?  That way you can just access by a key, like `1`, or `2`, etc

Comment: Yes, Matt, That is the case. Is there a way I could do something like this with the lists?

Comment: Maccettura, thank you for your time. I am new student and at this point I don't even know dictionnary existed :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for your issue is `FindName()` is looking for a XAML element by that name, its not going to check for class members.  So this line of code:

```
grid = (List<int>)this.FindName("grid" + Grid);
```

Will always be `null`, because `FindName("grid" + Grid)` will return `null`, then you are casting that `null` to a `List<int>`.  So `grid` will be a `null List<int>`

Having all these Lists in your class is a pretty *bad* design.  You can simplify things a bit by using a Dictionary.  I am not entirely sure I follow what your logic is, but this is my attempt to convert:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public Dictionary<int, List<int>> gridDictionary = new Dictionary<int, List<int>>();

    private bool numberValide(int number, int gridIndex)  // Grid {1..5}
    {
        //Checks if dictionary has an entry at gridIndex
        if(gridDictionary.ContainsKey(gridIndex))
        {
            if (!gridDictionary[gridIndex].Value.Contains(number))
            {
                //Add number to list in dictionary
                gridDictionary[gridIndex].Value.Add(number);  
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            //Adds a new entry to the dictionary with a list containing number
            gridDictionary.Add(gridIndex, new List<int>() { number });
            return true;
        }           
    }
```

Keep in mind that Dictionaries must have unique *keys*, so you couldn't do:

```
dictionary.Add(1, "one");
dictionary.Add(1, "uno");
```

That would throw an exception because a duplicate key exists already.  For your use case this *should* be fine because all your `grid` variables had to be uniquely named anyway to compile.

Comment: Works Perfectly, but I had to eliminate the Value of these two lines, maybe you could edit it  if (!gridDictionary[gridIndex].Value.Contains(number)) and gridDictionary[gridIndex].Add(number)

Answer (score 1):

I suspect the problem here is that you think FindName will let you find a field in a class. That is not what it does. It finds a control in a window. grid1, grid2, etc are not controls. They are fields

If you want to find fields, you would have to use reflection...but, the better way would be to just have a `List<List<int>>` instead.

So:

```
List<List<int>> grids = new List<List<int>>();
```

Then somewhere (maybe the constructor) you populate that list:

```
for (var i=0; i < numberOfGrids; i++) 
{
    grids.Add(new List<int>());
}
```

And then later when you want to retrieve a grid in your `numberValide`:

```
var grid = grids[Grid];   // where Grid is the index to your Grid - 
                          // your variable names are confusing
```

But now, since your original problem was to see if a number exists in any of your lists of ints, you can use Linq to simplify this greatly:

```
var doesExist = grids.Any(g => g.Contains(number));
```

Comment: Thank you so much Matt. This also works fine. I am pretty new here and even if your solution and Maccettura's work, It seems I can only select one answer as correct. I cannot even register my vote.